Ubuntu 24.04 Intel ARC support?
I have an XPS 15 9530 (2023) model which comes with Intel ARC A370M.
Everything works great but it seems the GPU does not work out of the box. On the official Intel page 24.04 is not even listed: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/747008/intel-arc-graphics-driver-ubuntu.html
Any ideas?

Does the Dell web site list that as a model that supports any version of Ubuntu?

Have you tried the SSU - https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/18895/26735/intel-system-support-utility-for-the-linux-operating-system.html And this is for older versions of Ubuntu: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/747008/intel-arc-graphics-driver-ubuntu.html  Issues with Wayland but not xorg.https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=289057  Have you tried both. I would expect older issues would be corrected in 24.04.

@oldfred ok, so it seems that it might be working. Just that in some games, I get a warning that I'm not using a dedicated GPU.

Intel's separate CPU is relatively new. Intel used to be just the internal video on CPU chip. So game may be only looking for nVidia or AMD.

@Pithikos what fixed the artifacts for you exactly? Did the artifacts occur only when moving the mouse? (Having issues with an Intel Ultra 155H with Arc iGPU here)

@hb0 I don't have any artifacts actually

Thanks, it was an issue with kernel 6.8.0-40. The internal non-touch display works fine with 6.8.9-36 kernel :))
